# The value of session variable changed to 'js' or 'css' Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have controller called 'projects' show all projects saved in db throught view and beside each project link to view its details which is send project id to the controller to select the clicked project and show its details.
I need to store the project id in session variable to use it over all of my proccess.
my problem is:
when i called the project id session variable -> at the first calling it is showing it correctly -> but in the second time calling it is showing 'js' or 'css'
I can't know what is the relation between my project id and 'js' or 'css' ??
Why the value changed ???

Here's my code:

admin_projects_view_view.php

```
<br />
<br />
<!--Page Container Start Here-->
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="widget-wrap">
                    <div class="widget-header block-header margin-bottom-0 clearfix">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <h3 style="font-size:25px">Projects</h3>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="widget-container">
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <!-------------------------- Projects---------------------------->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <a href="#" class="button round" data-reveal-id="newproject">Add New</a>
                                    <table id="headerTable" class="tablee">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">ID</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Name</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Location</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Description</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Quality</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Payment Method</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Project Map</td>
                                            <td class="event-td td-head text-center">Action</td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <?php
                                                foreach($view_projects as $row)
                                                {
                                                ?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->id ?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->pname?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->location ?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->description ?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->stars ?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->payment_methods ?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center"><?php echo $row->project_map ?></td>
                                                    <td class="event-td text-center">
                                                    <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/projects/view_project_details/<?php echo $row->id;?>">View Details </a>

                                            </td>
                                            <?php  } ?>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


            <div id="newproject" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
              <h2 id="modalTitle">Add New Project</h2>
                <form action="<?php echo site_url('projects/add_new'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" data-abide>

                        <label>Project Name: <small>required</small>
                        <input type="text" name="pname" placeholder="Project Name" >
                        </label>

                        <label>Location: <small>required</small>
                        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Project Location" >
                        </label>

                        <label>Description: <small>required</small>
                        <textarea name="description" placeholder="Project Description"  /></textarea>
                        </label>

                        <label>Quality: <small>required</small>
                        <input type="text" name="stars" placeholder="Project Quality" >
                        </label>

                        <label>Payment Method: <small>required</small>
                        <input type="text" name="payment_methods" placeholder="Payment Method" >
                        </label>

                        <label>Map: <small>required</small>
                        <textarea name="project_map" placeholder="Project Map"  /></textarea>
                        </label>

                    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" class="button round" />
                </form>
              <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
            </div>
```

projects controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Projects extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("session");
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model('projects_model');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
    }   


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('projects_model');
        $data['view_projects'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects();

        $this->load->view('admin_header_view');
        $this->load->view("admin_menu_view");
        $this->load->view("admin_projects_view_view", $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_footer_view');
    }

    public function view_project_details($id)
    {

        $sessdata=array(
            'project_id'=>$id
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($sessdata);    

        $data['view_projects_services'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_services($id);
        $data['view_projects_spaces'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_spaces($id);
        $data['view_projects_prices'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_prices($id);
        $data['view_projects_photos'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_photos($id);
        $data['view_projects_videos'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_videos($id);
        $data['view_projects_status'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_status($id);


        $this->load->view('admin_header_view');
        $this->load->view("admin_menu_view");
        $this->load->view("admin_projects_details_view", $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_footer_view');
    }

    public function view_project_details_session()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('project_id');
        //$data['view_one_project'] =  $this->projects_model->view_one_project_session($id);
        $data['view_projects_services'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_services($id);
        $data['view_projects_spaces'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_spaces($id);
        $data['view_projects_prices'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_prices($id);
        $data['view_projects_photos'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_photos($id);
        $data['view_projects_videos'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_videos($id);
        $data['view_projects_status'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_status($id);

        $this->load->view('admin_header_view');
        $this->load->view("admin_menu_view");
        $this->load->view("admin_projects_details_view", $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_footer_view');
    }

    //////////////////////////////////// Projects ////////////////////////////////////////////
    public function add_new_project()
    {

            $data= array(
                        'pname' => $this->input->post('pname'),
                        'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                        'stars' => $this->input->post('stars'),
                        'payment_methods' => $this->input->post('payment_methods'),
                        'project_map' => $this->input->post('project_map')
                    );
            $this->db->insert('projects',$data);

            redirect('projects');

    }

    public function edit_project($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('projects_model');
        $data['one_project'] =  $this->projects_model->view_one_project($id);

        $this->load->view('admin_header_view');
        $this->load->view("admin_menu_view");
        $this->load->view("admin_projects_edit_view", $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_footer_view');
    }

    public function save_project()
    {
        $project_id = $this->input->post('project_id');
        $data= array(
                    'pname' => $this->input->post('pname'),
                    'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    'stars' => $this->input->post('stars'),
                    'payment_methods' => $this->input->post('payment_methods'),
                    'project_map' => $this->input->post('project_map')
                );
        $this->db->where('id',$project_id);
        $this->db->update('projects',$data);

        redirect('projects');
    }

    public function delete_project($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('projects');

        redirect('projects');

    }
}
```

projects_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class projects_model extends CI_Model{

    public function view_projects()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('projects');
        return $query->result();
    } 

    public function view_one_project($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query=$this->db->get('projects');
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

print session variable value like:

```
<? echo $this->session->userdata('project_id');?>
```

admin_footer_view.php

```
<!--Footer Start Here -->
<footer class="footer-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="footer-left">
                    <span>© 2016 <a href="http://example.com"></a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="footer-right">
                    <span class="footer-meta">Designed by <a href="#"></a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!--Footer End Here -->
</section>
<!--Page Container End Here-->
<!--Rightbar Start Here--><!--Rightbar End Here-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jRespond.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/nav.accordion.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/hover.intent.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/hammerjs.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/scrollup.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.syntaxhighlighter.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/velocity.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery-jvectormap.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/smart-resize.js"></script>
<!--iCheck-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/icheck.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.switch.button.js"></script>
<!--CHARTS-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/easypie/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/curvedLines.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.stack.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/chart/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>

<!--Forms-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/j-forms.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/jquery.loadmask.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/vmap.init.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/lib/theme-switcher.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/apps.js"></script>


<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea please

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would account for this behaviour. The problem may be in other code not shown.

Comment: Well ideally SO requires that you post only pertinent code - otherwise it's TL;DR. Try to find occasions in your code where you're setting or ovewriting session vars and post that, rather than everything.

Comment: Is it possible that `$row->id` contains `css` or `js` value? Could you check the `projects` table?

Comment: Unfortunately id field contains 1 and 2 only and i checked all of the table and not found this two strings

Answer (score 0):

You are setting session variable name: 'project_id'

but in method "view_project_details_session", you are trying to get 'pid'
variable names different.

Comment: yes i Know and corrected it to 'project_id' but still the problem exists

Comment: print session variable "project_id" value in view_project_details method "admin_footer_view" , may be at the end of the method execution session variable is overwritten.

Comment: <? echo $this->session->userdata('project_id');?>

add this in admin_footer_view.php, what you get?

Comment: I got 'js' string and when i select project it changed to '1' and later changed to 'js' again

Comment: $data['view_projects_services'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_services($id);

$data['view_projects_spaces'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_spaces($id);
        $data['view_projects_prices'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_prices($id);
        $data['view_projects_photos'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_photos($id);
        $data['view_projects_videos'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_videos($id);
        $data['view_projects_status'] =  $this->projects_model->view_projects_status($id);

check these methods, one of them is updating session var

Comment: --OR--

one of these views, updating session var

$this->load->view('admin_header_view');
$this->load->view("admin_menu_view");
$this->load->view("admin_projects_details_view", $data);

Comment: and i noticed that the default value of this session variable always 'js'

Comment: shahid.ejaz47, come online at skype.

Comment: what is your skype?